# How to read, write, append the input file using perl

Tags: perl, overwrite

How to read and overwrite the same input file using perl?

My input:

```
GCGCCACTGCACTCCAGCCTGGGCGACAGAGC (873 TO 904)   GCTCTGTCGCCCAGGCTGGAGTGCAGTGGCGC (3033 TO 3064)
CAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (917 TO 936)   TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTG (2998 TO 3017)
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG (922 TO 941)   CTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT (2997 TO 3016)
```

I tried the below code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 
open($in,'<',"/home/httpd/cgi-bin/exa.txt") || die("error");
open($out,'>>',"/home/httpd/cgi-bin/exa.txt")||die("error");
while(<$in>)
{

print $out;
}
close $in;
close $out;
```

Answer (score 4):

Bear in mind what you're looking at doing here - you're opening a file for reading, reading it one line at a time.

What do you *think* is going to happen when you modify that file in the process?

There's also some constraints - Windows doesn't support concurrent opening for read/write anyway.

However take a look at [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) specifically:

> You can put a `+` in front of the `>` or `<` to indicate that you want both read and write access to the file; thus `+<` is almost always preferred for read/write updates--the `+>` mode would clobber the file first. **You can't usually use either read-write mode for updating textfiles, since they have variable-length records.** See the -i switch in perlrun for a better approach. The file is created with permissions of 0666 modified by the process's umask value.

What I would suggest instead though - don't read and write from the same file at all. Rename one, execute your process, verify that it worked properly, and *then* tidy up afterwards.

That way a partial success won't mean corrupted data.

You can use the `-i` flag - see [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) - this allows you to in place edit as you might be used to with `sed`. (Can be used within program via `$^I` - see [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) )

There's a couple of constraints on doing this though - specifically it *only* works if you're using the `while ( <> ) {` construct. Practically speaking, I think this wouldn't be a good choice outside more simplistic programs - it's doing something implicitly, so might not be entirely clear to future readers, and it's doing essentially the same thing as opening and renaming anyway.

Comment: can you expalin more ellaborative with some examples

Comment: Not really - what you're trying to do _doesn't work_ with plain text.